# How to calculate age from birthdate and timestamp in r?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
birthdate <- c("1993-06-27","1977-11-15","1988-08-12","1981-03-01")
timestamp <- c("2020-07-01 16:35:52","2020-07-01 16:48:55","2020-07-01 
16:53:42","2020-07-01 16:42:58")
df <- data.frame(birthdate,timestamp)
```

Based on these two columns (birthdate and completition date), I would like to calculate the age value for each id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)                 
library(lubridate)
id <- data.frame(birthdate= parse_date_time(c("1993-06-27","1977-11-15",
                                            "1988-08-12","1981-03-01",
                                            "1988-04-04"), '%Y-%m-%d'),
                 timestamp=parse_date_time(c("2020-07-01 16:35:52","2020-07-01 16:48:55",
                                             "2020-07-01 16:53:42","2020-07-01 16:42:58",
                                             "2020-07-01 16:45:50"), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

id<-id %>% mutate(age = as.numeric(difftime(timestamp,birthdate, units="weeks")/52))
```

Gives us

```
> id
   birthdate           timestamp      age
1 1993-06-27 2020-07-01 16:35:52 27.10630
2 1977-11-15 2020-07-01 16:48:55 42.77390
3 1988-08-12 2020-07-01 16:53:42 31.99644
4 1981-03-01 2020-07-01 16:42:58 39.47169
5 1988-04-04 2020-07-01 16:45:50 32.35357
```

Comment: I used this code: tc <- tc %>% mutate(age = as.numeric(difftime(sade_mental_comvc19_timestamp, comvc_sd_2, units="weeks")/52))
 But returned this error: 
Erro: Problem with `mutate()` input `age`.
x character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
i Input `age` is `as.numeric(...)`.

What could I do?

Comment: @MarcosO.C.Alves your input is not in date format. As I did in my answer, you'll need to parse your input so that it's in date format.

Comment: Thanks for both of you! The lab_rat_kid answer was a little more clear to me, but akrun has been help me a lot with other answers.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `difftime`

```
with(df1, as.numeric(difftime(timestamp, birthdate, units = 'weeks')/52))
```